# How to set up default local push path in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to set default local push path for Mercurial.
I do not need a remote server, instead I want to use my working directory as default path. How do I set it up?

My `hgrc` file does not work and looks like this:

```
[path]
default = /home/user/myscript/
default-push = /home/user/myscript/
```

Upon calling `hg push`, I get:

```
pushing to default
abort: repository default not found!
```

Comment: A clone of the repo must be present at that location. What is the path of your "working directory"?

Comment: `/home/user/myscript/` exactly the same, I work in this directory.

Comment: Does `/home/user/myscript` have a `.hg` folder in it?  If not, it isn't a repository so you can't push to it.

Comment: Why push at all if you are the only one using the repository?

Comment: yes , it has .hg and I can push to it. Just thought one can do it within one folder

Comment: When you only want to have single repository copy in one folder (your working folder) you don't have to push at all, just commit changes to the repository and that is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use:

```
[paths]
default = file:///home/user/myscript/
default-push = file:///home/user/myscript/
```